# Python regex: how to match strings that DO NOT contain an *exact* sentence?

Tags: python, regex

I want to filter out messages from a log file that contain e.g. the sentence `This is message 12345. Ignore.`

If I would use grep, I could simple pass the sentence and use the `-v` switch, for example:

```
grep -v "This is message 12345\. Ignore\." data.log
```

The thing is, I have to do this in Python. Something like:

```
import re
with open("data.log") as f:
    data = f.read()
# This will select all lines that match the given sentence
re.findall(".*This is message 12345\. Ignore\..*$", data)

# HERE --> I would like to select lines that DO NOT match that sentence
# ???
```

I've tried to use `(?...)` and `[^...]` syntax (see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)), but I couldn't get it right.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should use `^.*This is message 12345\. Ignore\..*$` along with the `m` modifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) like this:

```
re.findall("(?!^.*This is message 12345\. Ignore\..*$).*", data)
```

and also enable the `m` modifier, so that `^` and `$` match the start and the end of a row.

Comment: This is it. I was missing the `.*` at the end of the expression. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A simpler method to consider is to convert this to a positive matching problem:

- Go through the file line by line
- Perform a positive regex on the line, and if it matches, discard the line.

In general, negative matches with regexes get quite complicated.  It is usually easier and more efficient to use a positive match to find the things you don't want, and then exclude those things with programming logic.